# WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xXXXXXXXX error when calling C dll from Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have some c code like below. The return value is the pointer to a dynamic int array.

```
__declspec(dllexport) int32_t* foo(const alg_real_t* x, int32_t xlen)
{

....
result = (int32_t*)malloc( n * sizeof(int32_t));

....
return result;

}
```

I compiled it as dll and below is my code to call the function in python:

```
E = cdll.LoadLibrary('mydll.dll')
E.foo.restype  =  POINTER(c_int)
E.foo.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int),c_int]

s = (c_int * len(mydata))(*mydata) # mydata is a python list

Result = E.foo(s,len(mydata))
```

When I run the code, I often get an error msg:　"WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xXXXXXX". However, sometimes, the program runs without any error.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What's `alg_real_t`? In a type name, to me `real` implies a `double` precision float.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my puzzle! I changed my python code to: s=(c_double*len(ppg_data))(*ppg_data)        and it works like a charm.

Comment: A `double` is 64-bit, so the function was trying to read twice as many bytes as you were allocating in the `c_int` array. If reading beyond the array doesn't raise an access violation, that means it's in a larger block of allocated memory, which can lead to difficult to diagnose bugs. Getting an access violation at the immediate source of the problem is the best possible debugging scenario.